# why am I getting this cannot call 'macd' error?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to compare macd to the ema in pinescript and I am getting an error.

```
`macd(input(close), ema(close, 12), ema(close, 26)) > ema(close, 9)`
```

Error is: `line 12: Cannot call 'macd' with arguments (series[float], series[float], series[float]); available overloads: macd(series[float], integer, integer, integer) => [series[float], series[float], series[float]]; macd(fun_arg__<arg0_type>, fun_arg__<arg1_type>, fun_arg__<arg2_type>, fun_arg__<arg3_type>) => [series[float], series[float], series[float]];`

Answer (score 1):

`macd` function accept only integers as the lenght arguments, and you are trying to feed float values (ema(close, 12), ema(close, 26))

[image]